# What are the top most used satellite control system, flight dynamics solution at the moment ? Approx costs?

Tags: artificial-satellite, software, flight-control, mission-control

I am looking for a list of top most used satellite control systems, flight dynamics solutions by space agencies, private companies etc. the moment? How much do they cost approx for use by 1 person? Is there some website where I can get comparative feature ranking of them, so that I can make an informed choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Satellite control systems are usually created ad-hoc or based on existing in-house systems. For example, ESA reuses its own SCOS-2000 infrastructure.

In Europe, there are many companies that develop SCS like SSTL, GMV, SCISYS, DEIMOS, TERMA, and many more. There are also some open source systems like Cosmos and yamcs. In all the cases, you will have to customise then for your mission.

Regarding FDS, the best providers in Europe are GMV and DEIMOS.

Licenses are very very expensive and most of the SCS, FDS are custom solutions because they are heavily modified depending on the mission and the satellite. A single FDS could cost you between 30 k€ to more than 1M€. Again, there are open source frameworks like Orekit and commercial tools like STK but you will have to customise them.

I hope this help. If you have more questions or comments, please, let me know.

Best regards,
Alberto Fernandez